# Query on Bucketized Table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, bucket

I created a bucketized table as the following

```
drop table if exists bi_st.st_usr_member_active_day_test;
CREATE TABLE `bi_st.st_usr_member_active_day_test`(
`cal_dt_from` string,
  `cal_dt_to` string,
  `memberid` string, 
  `vipcode` string, 
  `vipleavel` string, 
  `cityid` string, 
  `cityname` string, 
  `groupid` int, 
  `groupname` string, 
  `storeid` int,
  `storename` string, 
  `sectionid` int, 
  `sectionname` string, 
  `promotionid` string, 
  `promotionname` string, 
  `moduleid` string, 
  `modulename` string, 
  `activeness_today` string, 
  `new_vip_class` string
  )
  clustered by (storeid) into 2 buckets 
  row format delimited fields terminated by '\t'
  stored as orc TBLPROPERTIES('transactional'='true');
```

And then inserted some data into it, and then I did 
`select * from bi_st.st_usr_member_active_day_test where storeid = 193;`, it failed and gave an array index out of bound error. Can anybody explain about this? Thanks

Comment: Not sure you might be hitting to hive bug. Try this once
SET hive.optimize.constant.propagation=false;

Comment: try creating the table without the clause  'row format delimited fields...". something doesn't add up for me with ORC + 'row format delimited fields..."